# Embed SVG Markup inside vue-component, using Raw-Loader

Tags: javascript, svg, webpack, vue.js

I am importing SVG with webpack [Raw-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/raw-loader). It means I want to embed the actual SVG XML inside my markup, as it is.

I am trying to do the following:

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{svgLoader}}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import svgLoader from '../assets/loader.svg'
export default {
  data: function () {
    return {
      svgLoader
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

However, I get the entire SVG XML as pure string and it doesn't get converted to the actual image.

Answer (score 2):

The SVG won't load because it will be escaped in the mode you are using as it could be a vulnerability. To allow it to render, use the `v-html` directive which will inject the RAW code allowing it to work.

This should **NEVER** be used for user generated content, only ever use it for content you trust.

```
<template>
  <div v-html="svgLoader"></div>
</template>

<script>
import svgLoader from '../assets/loader.svg'
export default {
  data: function () {
    return {
      svgLoader
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: what if I wanted to include inline svg within the template instead of importing something in? like one of these examples via MDN? https://codepen.io/akinhwan/pen/RQGyYW

Comment: In Vue 2.0 you could write a render function to produce an inline svg.